# Allow vim snipMate snippets to work on different file types

Tags: vim, snipmate, spf13vim

I am fairly new to vim and have been playing around with the [spf13](http://vim.spf13.com/) configuration, which is great.  The one thing I have not been able to figure out is how to allow snippets for one type of file to be used on another.  In my personal situation I wanted the javascript and javascript-jquery snippets to be used in html files.  Here is what I tried:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.html set ft=html.js

call ExtractSnipsFile(g:neosnippet#snippets_directory.'javacript-jquery.snippets','html')

let g:snipMate = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_alias = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_alias['html'] = 'html,javascript,javascript-jquery'

let g:snipMate = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases['html'] = 'html,javascript,javascript-jquery'
```

I have tried putting these lines in both the .vimrc.before.local and .vimrc.local files.

None of these seem to allow javascript snippets to work in html files.  I finally gave up and coped all the javascript and javascript-jquery snippets into the html snippet file.
That did the trick but I would love to know if there is another way.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. The first line should be enough to get what you want but the filetype for JavaScript files is not `js`, it's `javascript`.

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.html set ft=html.javascript
```

It gives you js omnicompletion as well.

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot! SPF13 is a gigantic and unecessary piece of crap: drop it ASAP.

Comment: Also it's `g:snipMate.scope_aliases` not `scope_alias`

Answer (score 2):

I used to use snipmate earlier and this was my configuration for it :

```
let g:snipMate = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases.haml = 'javascript'
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases.jade = 'javascript'
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases.markdown = 'html'
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases.javascript = 'javascript.d3,javascript-jquery'
```

You don't need to bother with setting compound filetypes and you don't have to specify filetypes themselves for which you're defining the scope aliases. This works perfectly fine and recursively. Since we've defined javascript filetypes to scope_alias also for javascript.dr & javascript-jquery, haml filetype above, having defined scope_alias for javascript gets all scope_aliases of javascript defined for it as well. You don't have to repeat yourself.

I am not sure about .vimrc.local or other files, I just put that in my .vimrc